# Can you [Authorize] a function that is not in a controller with asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am injecting services into my Blazor server pages that mimic my API. Can I use the `[Authorize]` attribute on the my service functions even though they are not controllers?

So far they don't seem to run, but I was wondering if there is more configuration I need to do. The policies do work on my controllers, so the ground work for start up and more is working.

Code:

```
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.CreateDepartment)]
public Department CreateDepartment (Department department)
{
    Department Department = DepartmentManager.CreateDepartment(department);
    return Department;
}
```

Once again, this is just in a basic C# class, not a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Create Attribute and filter there

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute:Attribute
{
//Create a code
}
```